# using if else in jadejs to create a body color or background image

Tags: node.js, express, pug

hello im using jade with nodejs and express to make webpages, in this case i want to use the if statement to create a body with differents styles...

here is the code

```
-if(image && image.length)
    body(style="background-image:url(#{image})")
-if(color && color.length)
    body(style="background-color:#{color}")


    h2 hello world
```

if background exists use background image

if color exists use a background-color

but the problem is when image exists the hello world or all the code indented on body doesnt work, if i put color up image when color exists the rest of the code is empty...

how can i solve this

EDIT 2:

im patching this problem using include in both statements

```
-if(image && image.length)
    body(style="background-image:url(#{image})")
    include restofcode
-if(color && color.length)
    body(style="background-color:#{color}")
    include restofcode
```

restofcode.jade

```
h2 hello world
```

and all works fine

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead of not being able to indent it properly:

```
- var myStyle = ''
- if(image && image.length) 
  - myStyle += "background-image:url(" + image + ");";
- if(color && color.length) 
  - myStyle += "background-color:" + color + ";";
body(style=myStyle)
    h2 Hello World
```

Comment: nope... not working, even when color is null, the body style="background-color:null", but when i erase if color statement the body takes the value of image and body style="background-image:url(/images/uno.jpg);